# React Native Hooks FlatList onEndReached

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I use react hooks,firebase to build a react native app.
I am pretty struggling about using Hooks with FlatList.
I am trying to creating pagination with Firestore. However, I am not sure how to trigger `onEndReached` using `useEffect`

It is what I tried:

```
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)

   useEffect(() => {
    if(isFetching == false){
        _initFirestoreQuery()
    }
}, [])

_initFirestoreQuery = async()=>{
    const limit = 6
    const initialQuery = firebase.firestore().collection('xxxx').orderBy('displayName', 'desc').limit(limit)
    const documentSnapshots = await initialQuery.get()
    const documentData = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());
    const lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1].displayName;
    setLast(lastVisible)
    setData(documentData)
    setIsFetching(true)
}

_moreFirestoreQuery = async () =>{
    if(isFetching == true){
    const limit = 6
    const additionalQuery = firebase.firestore().collection('xxxx').orderBy('displayName', 'desc').startAfter(last).limit(limit)
    const documentSnapshots = await additionalQuery.get();
    const documentData = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());
    const lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1].displayName;
    setLast(lastVisible)
    setData(data =>[...data,...documentData])
    }
}
  <FlatList
  onEndReached ={_moreFirestoreQuery}
  ...
  >
```

Any Idea of doing this if it is impossible how could I do it and is there any alternative for doing this

Comment: Why `useEffect`? Why not simply setting the state? Can you post the full code to have more context?

Comment: so do you mean I just have to do `onEndReached={() => 
loadMoreData()}` ? set condition to call the method?

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do, without giving me more details, but as far as I can see that might just do the trick.

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: `onEndReached` will be triggerred base on `onEndReachedThreshold`. When you scroll your list, if the scroll position is within the threshold, it will trigger `onEndReached`. By default, the value of `onEndReachedThreshold` is 0.5